# Display Data on new row if array in json is greater than 1

Tags: json, angular, typescript, mat-table

I am making a call to an Api in Angular and displaying the data on a mat-table in Angular 7.

The Response is something like this

```
{
            "promo": "Mon",
            "start": "2019",
            "carrier": "[UPS Ground, UPS Express, UPS Expedited]",
            "end": "2020",
            "shipTime": "[10, 2Day, Overnight]",
            "price": "[0.0, 14.99, 24.99]", 
        }
```

I am displaying this Data on a Mat Table like this

```
Mon|2019| [UPS Ground, UPS Express, UPS Expedited] | 2020 | [10, 2Day, Overnight]| [0.0, 14.99, 24.99]

But i want to display it like this 

Mon | 2019 | UPS Ground | 2020 |10 | 0.0

Mon | 2019 | UPS Express | 2020 |2day| 14.99

Mon | 2019 | UPS Expedited | 2020 | Overnight | 24.99
```

Is there any advice, link, or tutorial that i can be pointed to? I have search around and can't find anything.

Thank you

Comment: try and make your question more specific. The angular material docs contains examples for Mat Table https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview.

Comment: `carrier`, `shipTime`, `price` always have the same length?

Comment: yes it will always be the same length @ajai jothi

Comment: @shusson i don't understand, isn't my question specific enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the `carrier` `price` and `shipTime` has the same length. Now you can loop through `modifiedInput` to display in a table.

```js
const input = [{
  "promo": "Mon",
  "start": "2019",
  "carrier": ['UPS Ground', 'UPS Express', 'UPS Expedited'],
  "end": "2020",
  "shipTime": ['10', '2Day', 'Overnight'],
  "price": ['0.0', '14.99', '24.99']
},{
  "promo": "Tue",
  "start": "2019",
  "carrier": 'UPS Ground',
  "end": "2020",
  "shipTime": 'Overnight',
  "price": '14.99'
}];

const modifiedInput = input.reduce((output, item) => {
  if(item.carrier instanceof Array) {
    item.carrier.forEach((carrier, index) => {
      output.push({
        ...item,
        carrier,
        shipTime: item.shipTime[index],
        price: item.price[index]
      });
    });
  } else {
    output.push(item);
  }

  return output;
}, []);

console.log(modifiedInput);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: wasn't available to thumbs up yesterday. It worked, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to re-format the data yourself, preferably in your Angular service where you fetch the data initially.

Assuming the carrier, shipTime, and price arrays are always equal length and in corresponding order, the below should work.

```
const newResp = [];
resp.forEach(promo => {
  promo.carrier.forEach((carrier, i) => {
    const shipTime = promo.shipTime[i];
    const price = promo.price[i];
    newResp.push({ ...promo, carrier, shipTime, price });
  });
});
return newResp;
```

This code is creating a new entry in the newResp list for each carrier in each promotion. If a promotion doesn't have any carriers, no entries will be created for that promotion.